# If no result then another query, can be combined to one query?

Tags: sql, oracle, jpql

```
Phone_book
+----+---------+-----------+--------------+
| id | key     | code      |    value     |
+----+---------+-----------+--------------+
| 1  | MAX_VAL | 111       |    reset     |
+----+------+--------------+--------------+
| 2  | MIN_VAL | 222       |    set       |
+----+------+--------------+--------------+
| 3  | MIN_VAL | 0         |    NA        |
+----+---------+-----------+--------------+
```

Key and code combination is the primary key.

**Requirement:**

if KEY and CODE is present, return VALUE.

if KEY is present and CODE not exist return the VALUE of CODE 0.

**Implementation:**

Achieved this with using multiple query. Syntax used is for JPQL

1) `"SELECT param FROM Phone_book param WHERE upper(key)=:paramKey AND code=:estCode";`

if this returns null, while shoot another query

2) `"SELECT param FROM Phone_book param WHERE upper(key)=:paramKey AND code=:O";`

**What I looking for :**

Can I achieve this in one query, or a better way ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle SQL, the below will suffice your need. No need to write PLSQL for this.

```
SELECT key,
       nvl(code,0)                            -- This will make sure if code is null then value is 0
FROM Phone_book  
WHERE (key is not NULL AND CODE IS NOT NULL)  -- This will help in fetching value when KEY and CODE is present
OR ( key is not null and code is null);       -- This will help in fetching value  when KEY is present and CODE is null.
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>MySQL</kbd>  <sub>Relevant because the question was tagged `MySQL` initially</sub>

You can give it a try:

```
SELECT 
defaultTable.`key`,
COALESCE(queryTable.`value`,defaultTable.`value`) AS v
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    `key`,
    `value`
    FROM Phone_book 
    WHERE UPPER(`key`) = ?
    AND `code` = 0
) AS defaultTable

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    `key`,
    `value`
    FROM Phone_book 
    WHERE UPPER(`key`) = ?
    AND `code` = ?
) AS queryTable
ON defaultTable.`key` = queryTable.`key`;
```

**Note:** Replace the question marks by your provided values.

When there doesn't exist any record for the supplied `key` and `code` values then `queryTable.value` will be `NULL`.

So `COALESCE` will pick the value from `defaulTable` if any.

Comment: Is this query for Plsql ? DB  is plsql.

Comment: There's `mysql` tag in your question and this is raw mysql query.

Comment: Ok, added by mistake, will try to convert this to plsql.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
case 
   when key is not null and code is not null then value
   when key is not null and code is null then 0
end 
from phone_book;
```

Comment: Look at the table columns mentioned above  and reply properly. This will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
select value from (
  select value, row_number() over (order by case when code = 0 then 2 else 1 end) rn
    from phonebook pb 
    where upper(key) = :paramKey and (code = :estCode or code = 0))
  where rn = 1
```

Select values having requested key and requested code or code 0. Sort them properly with function `row_number` and take first value.